# JavaScript push Array into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-geocoder

I'm currently working with Google maps' geocoding and need to create an array that will contain arrays as an elements.

Basically i need to create this:

```
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];
```

But dynamically!
I need this array to put pins on a map later.

What I'm doing:

```
        var locations = []; // The initial array
        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; ++i){

            var address=addresses[i]; // the address e.g. 15 Main St, Hyannis, MA
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results){
                var obj = {
                    0: address,
                    1: results[0].geometry.location.hb,
                    2: results[0].geometry.location.ib,
                    3: i
                };
                console.log(obj);
                locations.push(new Array());
                locations[i].push(obj);

            });
        };

        console.log(locations.length);
```

**The problem, question:**

I don't see any errors but at the end locations[] array is empty.

Here is a console screen if needed:

[image]

Comment: `geocode` is async. You need to wait for ALL calls to reply before processing the array.

Comment: Hm. I thought loop should be finished for script to continue? no?

Comment: The basic way to push an empty array into another away isn't obvious in this question, so I'll point out that for an array it's `myArray.push(new Array())`. `myArray` must at least be instantiated to an empty array i.e. `myArray = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't have time to test the code, but it should work this way:

```
    function requestLocations( addresses, callback ) {
        var remainingLocations = addresses.length;
        var locations = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; ++i){

            var address=addresses[i]; // the address e.g. 15 Main St, Hyannis, MA

            locations[i] = [];

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, (
                function(idx) {
                    return function(result) {
                        locations[idx] = [  addresses[idx], 
                                            results[0].geometry.location.hb,
                                            results[0].geometry.location.ib,
                                            idx
                                        ];

                        //decrement the number of remaining addresses
                        --remainingLocations;

                        //if there are no more remaining addresses and a callback is provided then call this calback with the locations
                        if( remainingLocations === 0 && callback ) {
                            callback(locations);
                        }               
                    }; // returns the real callback function for your geocoding

                })(i) //direct invocation of function with paramter i for scoping
            );

        }
    }


    requestLocations(addresses, function( locations ) {
        console.dir(locations);
        console.log(locations.length);
    });
```

The Problem with your code is the following. First this part of the code is executed:

```
        var locations = []; // The initial array
        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; ++i) {

            var address = addresses[i]; // the address e.g. 15 Main St, Hyannis, MA
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(results) {
                //this part is called later when that data is ready (it is an asynchronous callback)

            });
        };

        //because of the async request this is still 0
        console.log(locations.length);
```

After that the callbacks itself are called as soon as the browser receives the data from the server:

```
      function(results) {
        var obj = {
            0: address,
            1: results[0].geometry.location.hb,
            2: results[0].geometry.location.ib,
            3: i
        };
        console.log(obj);
        locations.push(new Array());
        locations[i].push(obj);

      }
```

Comment: Awesome! :D Just tested it! IT WORKS! Thank you for detailed answer and work on my code :) +1

Comment: @rinchik there was a bug in it `addresse` should have been  `addresses[idx]` in the callback. please recheck your code, otherwise you will always have the same address in your result.

Comment: Hmm... quick question! for some reason for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; ++i) loop loops only 12 times and then stops. If i put console.log(remainingLocations); here is the output: http://screencast.com/t/ENbhFdpaDRcE Do you have any idead why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

This should be all you need:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results){
            locations.push([
              address,
              results[0].geometry.location.hb,
              results[0].geometry.location.ib,
              i //this is actually going to always be 
                //addresses.length because the callback won't fire
                //until well after the loop has completed. 
                //Is this really a necessary field to have 
                //in your array? if so, you'll need to refactor a bit
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: Makes sense... but console.log(locations.length); still shows 0

Comment: @rinchik probably because `geocoder.geocode()` is async... and `locations` hasn't changed by the time you log it.

Comment: See Prinzhorn's comment on your question...it's async, you need to only fire the `console.log` after all geocodes have been finished

Comment: @BLSully you should mention that `i` will always be `addresses.length` because of scoping